# Миллисекунды в таймере android

Tags: java, android

Я недавно начал разбираться с таймером в android. У меня есть вот такой код, но мне нужно, чтобы миллисекунды доходили до 60, а не до 10 (и при этом не было рассинхрона с реальным временем, именно это у меня не получалось) подскажите пожалуйста, как мне это сделать?

```
private void startTimer() {
    timer = new Timer();
    btnStart.setText(R.string.btn_stop);
    running = true;
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runTimer();
        }
    }, 0, 100);
}

private void runTimer() {
    this.runOnUiThread(timerTick);
}

private void updateMs() {
    ms++;
    if (ms == 10) {
        updateSeconds();
    }
}

private void updateSeconds() {
    ms = 0;
    seconds++;
    if (seconds == 60) {
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;
    }
    if (minutes == 60) {
        updateHor();
    }
}

private void updateHor() {
    minutes = 0;
    hourse++;
    if (hourse == 60) {
        ms = 0;
        minutes = 0;
        hourse = 0;
    }
}

private void updateTimerText() {
    timerText.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%01d:%02d:%02d:%02d", hourse, minutes, seconds, ms));
}

private Runnable timerTick = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        updateTimerText();
        updateMs();
    }
};
```

Comment: `ms` у Вас не миллисекунды - а что-то абстрактное, равное 100 миллисекунд. Задержка выставляется целочисленно, в одной секунде 1000 миллисекунд, что не делится на 60, откуда очевидно следует, что то, что Вы хотите сделать, нельзя сделать без рассинхрона. Другое дело, если Вам просто нужно каждые 60 миллисекунд что-то делать помимо этой задачи - тогда все очень просто.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите вообще без рассинхрона - то не получится(по крайней мере я не знаю простых способов)

Почему? Ну например, есть поток А(спящий) и ещё 10 потоков. Вот поток А подождал нужное для вас время(10 мс или нет - не важно). Дальше он проснулся, но не факт, что он сразу же начнёт своё выполнение. Планировщик может отдать следующие такты процессора другим потокам из 10и.

И когда А продолжит своё выполнение, в действительности пройдёт больше чем 10мс

Comment: Таймеры в этом плане сравнительно надежны. Рассинхрон будет, конечно, но на уровне обычных электронных часов. И ничто не мешает вместо сложения каждый раз запрашивать текущее время, тогда промаха более чем на миллисекунду для пользователя никогда не будет)

Comment: Соглашусь, вариант с запрашиванием текущего времени намного надёжнее.